# How can I show or hide image which in listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview where I am storing my all the data,there is an imagebutton i want it when My textview length is not null then I want it visible.so can i do this..I am using this code.

```
d1 = cursor1.getCount();
if(d1>0)
{
   for(cursor1.moveToPosition(-1);cursor1.moveToNext();cursor1.isAfterLast()){
   String businessname1 = cursor1.getString(2);
   ImageButton imagebutton = (ImageButton)l.findViewById(R.id.imageButton201);
   if(rewardvoucherpercetage1.length()==0)
   {
       imagebutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
   }
   HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
   temp.put("businessname", businessname1);
```

can I do this..Can anyone help me..

thank you

Comment: show us the code where you populate the listview.

Comment: You have to show us more code of how you populate the listview.

Comment: imagebutton.setVisibility(View.Gone);

Comment: ok where I have to send my code..

Comment: edit ur Question and post your code.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can hide your image button by writing this code in your If condition

```
     imagebutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     or 
     imagebutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: When i am doing this then All the page has gone.nothing is diaplay

Comment: ok then how many items/image button does your listview contains or give some approx size

Comment: actually I am taking a whole layout in a list view then in those layout having image button

Comment: I want to hide it when there is no data in my field

Answer (score 0):

```
if(rewardvoucherpercetage1.length()==0)
{
    imagebutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
    imagebutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```